# Handle tap on notification if App is in killed state iOS

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, push

I am using firebase push notification, everything is running fine when app is in background and foreground state. But when app is in killed state, tap on notification leads to home page. I have used all possible ways- by using launch option check

```
if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as?  [AnyHashable : Any] {

        if let userInfo = remoteNotification as? [String : Any]
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1.0, execute: {
            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
            let notificationManager = PushNotificationManager()
            notificationManager.handleNotificationAction(data: userInfo)
        })
        }
    }
```

I don't know what I am missing. Please help.

Comment: `1.` Where you writing this code? `2.` In which controller you wanted to land in above mentioned scenario?

Comment: Did you read `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` documentation? You can reach out here by clicking (⊞ + click) on this. You will get the solution of your query.

Comment: I am writing this code App Delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method and want to open a controller which will be decided by the user info content data by handleNotification method @dahiya_boy

Comment: can you add code of handleNotifiationAction method?

Comment: yeah I have updated the question, please check now

Comment: @NikitaSrivastava also please add code for getNavigationController and goToGenericPushScreen

Comment: thanks @Hitesh this link really helped me, by handling the notification on Home Page instead of app delegate.

Comment: Glad to hear from you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   In your appdelegate add this extension.

   extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, 
                            withCompletionHandler
                            completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "login_session") {
        let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", 
        bundle: nil)
        let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = 
         mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Notifs_Main") as UIViewController
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    } else {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isLoggedin")
        print("failed")
    }
    return completionHandler()
    }
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent
    notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler:
    @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    return completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert)
   }
 }
```

Comment: I have already used these methods but they are not working when app is in killed state -func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
          if let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? [String : Any] {
            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
            let notificationManager = PushNotificationManager()
            notificationManager.handleNotificationAction(data: userInfo)
        } completionHandler() }

Comment: but are you getting a notification when the app is running on background?

Comment: yeah everything is working fine when app in running or background state, these delegate methods are getting called in that scenario but not in killed state so its opening the home page

Comment: may I see your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?